# Can I declare a string in a header file in a definition of a class?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to declare a string at all in a header (.h) file, in the definition of a Class?

When I want to set a default `int`, I do:

```
 class MyClass
 {
     static const unsigned int kDATA_IMAGE_WIDTH =  1024;
```

Is there a way to do the same for the `string` object?

```
 class MyClass
 {
      static const string kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION = "png"; // fail
```

I know I can use `#define`...

```
 #define kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION "png"
```

thanks

edit: added that it is in a class definition. updated examples.

Comment: What compiler are you using and what's the error? That works for me.

Comment: Xcode (gcc is it?) error is :  
`error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const std::string'`

Comment: Are you sure you are within the right namespace. Try std::string. Are you doing this inside a class?

Comment: @Ross: Well, is it in a class? Being in a class makes that statement hugely different (and invalid). Outside of a class definition it is fine.

Comment: Uhm... declaring variables like that in a header file is not recommended.

Comment: I think so. Tried adding `std::string`but sadly still not working...

Comment: @George interesting. Not even for some default values? Are `includes` better or something else?

Comment: @Ross: Declaring a variable tells the compiler to set aside space for that variable. Every source file that includes it will then try to reserve space for it - and because it will have the same name in each case, the linker will report an error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the error message you gave (emphasis mine):

> error: invalid **in-class** initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const std::string'

You can do this in a header file, but you cannot do so in a class.

That is:

```
class MyClass
{
    static const std::string invalid = "something";
};
```

is not valid, but

```
static const std::string valid = "something else";
```

is valid.

If you want the static to be a member of the class only, you do this:

```
//Header
class MyClass
{
    static const std::string valid;
};


//Implementation (.cpp) file

const std::string MyClass::valid = "something else again";
```

Only **static const integral** class variables may be initialized using the "= *constant*" syntax.

Comment: Sorry, it is within a class definition. I've updated my question. Thanks

Comment: @Ross: Well then my answer doesn't change. ;) The last codebox tells you how to do this correctly.

Comment: I had to remove the `static` keyword from the implementation (.cpp) file.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but strings are not intrinsic to C++. you need the proper #include

```
#include <string>

static const std::string kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION = "png";
```

On a side note. I've never seen C++ code use the k prefix to denote a constant. I think that's an Objective-C convention. Also, ALL_CAPS symbols should really be reserved for #define macros, not language constants.

Comment: hmmm, thanks, but not working me?... : `error: invalid in-class initialization of static data member of non-integral type 'const std::string'`

Comment: I did not realize you were trying to do this inside a class.

Comment: Appologies... my inexperience, I should have mentioned it.

Comment: thanks for this extra info, it is great. I am coming from Obj-C to C++.

Comment: A 'k' prefix on C++ constant variables is part of the [Google C++ style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml#Constant_Names)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to declare strings or put any other sort of code in your header file.  It might be failing because the header file is missing the #include which defines string, or you need to put a "std::" in front of it if you aren't "using namespace std" in the header file.

Please update your question with the specific compiler error you're seeing if these suggestions don't fix it.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the context here, but if the intent is to define an immutable array of characters terminated by a '\0', why not use:

static const char kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION[] = "png";

Also, note that there's no transparent conversion between string class and const char * without invoking string::c_str()..

Answer (score 0):

Two choices:

Define a function in the header that is static and returns the string you want.

```
static std::string kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION()
    {
        return "png";
    }
```

A macro will do the right thing here

```
#define STATIC_STRING_IN_HEADER(name,value) static std::string name(){return value;}
STATIC_STRING_IN_HEADER(kDEFAULT_FILE_EXTENSION,"png")
```